# How to use a Helper from Plugin A in Plugin B in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two plugins in CakePHP. I want to use  View/Helpers/SomeHelper.php from plugin A in a controller from plugin B. I tried a few things like uses() but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You question is very broad as it stands.  Please add a code example and further explanation of what the problems are.  Error outputs are usually helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both plugins are loaded in `boostrap.php`

In your “B” Controller simply type:

```
public $helpers = array('PluginNameA.HelperName');
```